# Mysql with android

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am creating an app like Instagram. And I need to use a database right? so I chose MYSQL but I have no idea about how to host the database so that all the users can access the data and how to connect the app with the database. I watched a lot of tutorials on how to connect the database with the app but none of them helped. So can you guys provide me with information on how to host the database and a good example to connect the database with the app. Please..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use database in 2022 there are two good options.

1. First one is using Google Firebase

To get started with Firebase go through this : https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352

And to understand better this tutorial playlist will help : https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuBf5KH4XXOthtgo6E4Epjl8

2. Second best way to create database is using Room Library instead of using SQLite. Room is easy to use and understand.

Here is the playlist to get you started with Room in Android : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hg_ywZffPgRTmJoy2XWs02d

Comment: room database can be used for social media apps? I thought it is used to store data locally.